# What does the builtin function any() do?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, any

I did some google searching on how to check if a string has any elements of a list in it and I found this bit of code that works:

`if any(i in string for i in list):`

I know this works, but I don't really know why.  Could you share some insight?

Comment: The documentation for [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) describes exactly what it does. What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: My guess is that what's _actually_ confusing you here isn't the `any` function, but rather the generator expression being passed as an argument to it. For that, read the tutorial section on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), then skip ahead to [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) and generator expressions.

Comment: @abarnert I know that any will return true if any element of the iterator is true.  I get confused with how the part of the code before the `for` fits in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the docs for [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) say:

> Return `True` if any element of the *iterable* is true. If the *iterable* is empty, return `False`. Equivalent to:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

So, this is equivalent to:

```
for element in (i in string for i in list):
    if element:
        return True
return False
```

… which is itself effectively equivalent to:

```
for i in list:
    element = i in string
    if element:
        return True
return False
```

---

If you don't understand the last part, first read the tutorial section on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), then skip ahead to [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators), generators, and generator expressions.

If you want to really break it down, you can do this:

```
elements = []
for i in list:
    elements.append(i in string)
for element in elements:
    if element:
        return True
return False
```

That still isn't exactly the same, because a generator expression builds a generator, not a list, but it should be enough to get you going until you read the tutorial sections.

---

But meanwhile, the point of having `any` and comprehensions and so on is that you can almost read them as plain English:

```
if any(i in string for i in list): # Python

if any of the i's is in the string, for each i in the list: # pseudo-English
```

Comment: That last part really helped me get it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
i in string for i in list
```

This produces an iterable of booleans indicating whether each item in `list` is in `string`. Then you check whether any item in this iterable of bools is true.

In effect, you're checking whether any of the items in the list are substrings of `string`.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here with:

```
if any(i in string for i in list):
```

is best explained by illustrating:

```
>>> xs = ["Goodbye", "Foo", "Balloon"]
>>> s = "Goodbye World"
>>> [i in s for i in xs]
[True, False, False]
>>> any([i in s for i in xs])
True
```

If you read the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) documentaiton you'll note:

> `any(iterable)` Return True if any element of the iterable is true.
>   If the iterable is empty, return False. Equivalent to:

The list comprehension should be more obvious as it constructs a list of `i in s` for each element of `xs`.

Basically (*in English*) you are returning any match where each sub-string exists in the search string (*haystack*).

It's important to note as well that `any()` will short circuit and end on the first `True`(*ish*) value it finds. `any()` can be implement in pure Python like this:

```
def any(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        if x:
            return True
    return False
```